# Why does my dynamically loaded data-ng-options angularjs select list not work correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an angularjs select list declared (as part of a Bootstrap modal form) as follows:

```
     <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="modelName" id="someId" data-ng-options="item.itemName as item.text for item in items">
         <option selected="selected" value="">Please select an option</option>
     </select>
```

The data is loaded via ajax. In my controller, as part of the Ajax response handler I have:

```
$scope.items = items;
$scope.modelName= $scope.items [0];
```

This all works as expected. The modal dialog is displayed as a result of the user clicking a button on the page. When it is displayed the select list is there, populated with the expected values. However the first time I select anything from the list, regardless of which dynamic items I select the last option is the one that gets selected. Weirdly any subsequent selections work. It only ever happens the first time. It also only happens if I select one of the items loaded via Ajax. If I select the placeholder this works just fine. Any ideas as to how this behaviour can be remedied would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify the AngularJS version that you are using?  Also something to point out here: Your $scope.modelName is bound to the item object, not the item's itemName as it should according to the ng-options expression ("item.itemName as ...").

Comment: Setting the model correctly, as per your suggestion fixed the issue. Huge thanks for pointing this out, you have saved me hours of frustration. Much appreciated!